# Workflow 2013 still not available in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server

I have already followed all of the steps to configure workflow manager in my SharePoint server, but it is still not showing in SharePoint Designer.

Here are the steps I followed: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588.aspx

Comment: did you validate your installation, steps mentioned at the end of same technet.

Comment: I had the same issue - it's probably either a problem with the service registration OR the client install. The client has to be installed on whichever server you're accessing via Designer. Ideally, it should be on all servers in the farm.

Comment: You may want to list the steps that you followed in your own words, and provide more information about your environment.

Answer (score 0):

You must install all of the updates of Sharepoint Designer 2013. I downloaded these: spd2013-kb3039732 and spdsp2013-kb2817441.